# Вырезать код Google Analytics регулярным выражением php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такой вот блок от Google Analytics:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-*******-*', 'auto');  // Replace with your property ID.
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Набросал короткую регулярку для устранения этого самого блока из html странички:

```
 $buffer=preg_replace("/<script>\n\(function\(i,s,o,g,r,a,m\)(.*?)google-analytics\.com\/analytics\.js(.*?)<\/script>/is","", $buffer, -1, $count);
```

К сожалению ничего не удаляется, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать регулярку для удаления данного блока?

Comment: `<script>\n\(function\(i,s,o,g,r,a,m\)(.*?)google-analytics\.com\/analytics\.js.*?<\/script>`  вы зачем то ждете \n после analytics.js и не ожидаете последующие символы. проверяйте регулярки на regex101.com. Достаточно было просто поудалять куски и посмотреть что подходит.

Comment: опечатался, там хотел написать (.*?) вместо \n, исправил

Comment: А вы свою регулярку в preg_replace в одинарные кавычки заключите. А то двойные обрабатывают обратные косые и они до интерпретатора регулярок не доходят

Comment: сделал, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Странно. У меня скопированная от вас регулярка, в одинарных кавычках отлично вырезает весь указанный вами блок. Из подозрительных мест вижу только переводы кареток, которые у вас могут быть \r\n например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверняка можно ещё больше укоротить, но если не хочется терять читаемость...

```
$buffer = preg_replace("#<script>[^>]+google-analytics[^>]+</script>#",
                       "", $buffer);
```

Comment: при этом остальные яваскрипты не будут удаляться?

Comment: @valextt будут удаляться только те, которые содержат в себе строку `google-analytics`